# Python: Caesar cipher encryption

Tags: python, encryption, shift

Hello everyone I have a question. Why doesn't the following code dont produce any output or errors?

This is a code that encrypts and decrypts user codes

```
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',
     'g','h','i','j','k','l',
     'm','n','o','p','q','r',
     's','t','u','v','w','x',
     'y','z']

shift = range(26)

def user_info():
    info = input("\nPress 'e' to encrypt or 'd' to decrypt: ").lower()
    if info == 'e' or 'd':
       return info

def user_message():
    code = input("What is your message?: ")
    return code

def user_shift():
     shift = int(input("What is your shift number?: "))
     while True:
         if shift == int(shift):
             return shift

def True_Message(info, code, shift):

    if info[0] == 'd':     #This encrypts the code 
         shift = -shift    

    for letter in code:
        if letter in alpha:
        alpha_2 = ord(letter) + shift
        secret_message = ""
    if alpha_2 in range (0, len(alpha)):
        final_mix = chr(alpha)
        secret_message += final_mix

return secret_message

info = user_info()
code = user_message()
shift = user_shift()
print(True_Message(info, code, shift))
```

There aren't any errors so I don't know what is wrong. I'm new at this encryption stuff, I'm not sure if this is even on the right track, any ideas? Thank you.

**UPDATE!!!!!**

Sorry I'm expecting the code to be able to encrypt and decrypt codes based on users choice

Comment: What is the current code doing and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: You have some indentation problems in `True_Message`... could you fix those?

Comment: you have 2 indention issues. but presuming those are not the problem, this line: secret_message = "" is likely killing the output. Check the value of alpha_2 after that line, see if it is in the range you are expecting. otherwise, your secret message is going to be blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check your indentation and your usage of the `or` operator:

```
alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',
     'g','h','i','j','k','l',
     'm','n','o','p','q','r',
     's','t','u','v','w','x',
     'y','z']

shift = range(26)

def user_info():
    info = input("\nPress 'e' to encrypt or 'd' to decrypt: ").lower()
    if info in ('e', 'd'): # 'or' does not work how you think it does
        return info

def user_message():
    code = input("What is your message?: ")
    return code

def user_shift():
     while True:
         shift = int(input("What is your shift number?: "))
         if shift == int(shift):
             return shift

def True_Message(info, code, shift):

    if info[0] == 'd':     #This encrypts the code 
         shift = -shift    

    for letter in code:
        if letter in alpha:
            alpha_2 = ord(letter) + shift
            secret_message = ""
    if alpha_2 in range (0, len(alpha)):
        final_mix = chr(alpha)
        secret_message += final_mix

    return secret_message
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is an indentation-sensitive language. You have indentation errors all over the place.

How can you say "There aren't any errors" - are you running the script? The python interpreter will tell you exactly where they are. When I run your script:

```
C:\Users\Jonathon\temp>python caesar.py
  File "caesar.py", line 22
    return shift
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

So your first error is here:

```
def user_shift():
     shift = int(input("What is your shift number?: "))
     while True:
         if shift == int(shift):
         return shift              # ---> Should be indented one more level
```

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an error? (they said they didn't get any errors)

Comment: @Xymostech Yes. Just finished adding that bit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart he probably entered the code into the SO editor wrong.

Comment: My apologies. While I did indent `return shift` in my code I didn't show that here.

Answer (score 1):

As others say, you have some indentation problem.

For the logic level, you should definitively check if `secret_message = ""` is what you want.
Other points:

- What if the `letter` is `Z` and you add a shift ? ([Check the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/))
- Are you sure you want the shift to be a `range(26)` in first place ? Try `print(list(range(26)))` to see what is going on with the range.

And don't discourage yourself, playing with the ASCII can be frustrating at first but once familiarized it can be very fun !

Answer (score -3):

Nah, check this out.

```
from tkinter import *

                        #Functions. The first three do the job. The rest are about GUI
def wordlist(a):
    word_list=(list(a))
    return (word_list)

def length(a):
    return(len(wordlist(a))-1)

def encrypt(a,b):
    thelist=wordlist(a)
    i=0
    while i<=(length(a)):
        thelist[i]=(chr(ord(wordlist(a)[i])+(b)))
        i=i+1
    return (''.join(thelist))

def callback():    
    e.focus_set()
    a=e.get()

    e2.focus_set()
    b=int(e2.get())

    e3.delete(0, (length(a)+1))
    e3.insert(0,(encrypt(a,b)))

                        #User Interface

root = Tk(className="_Caesar Cipher Encryptor")


frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

frame2= Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

frame3=Frame(root)
frame3.pack()


enter=Label(frame1, text="Enter Text:", bd=3, font="Ariel")
enter.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)

shift=Label(frame2, text="Shift:", font="Ariel")
shift.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)

result=Label(frame3,text="Encrypted Code:", font="Ariel")
result.pack(side=LEFT)


e= Entry(frame1,width=50, font="Ariel")
e.pack(side=RIGHT)

e2= Entry(frame2,width=10, font="Ariel")
e2.pack(side=LEFT)

e3=Entry(frame3, font="Ariel")
e3.pack(side=RIGHT)


b = Button(frame2, text="Encrypt", width=10, command=callback, font="Ariel")
b.pack(side=RIGHT)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow! It's always a good idea to accompany code with a description what the code is supposed to be doing and *how* it solves the problem presented in the question. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28261647/edit) your answer to improve it.